# how can I show image of my blogs (in collection type) in Nuxt with Strapi cms?

Tags: json, nuxt.js, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I want show my img of my blogs in Nuxt with Strapi but I can not do it
I log my blogs you can see json data:

[image]

I use this code but it does not work !

```
<template>
  <div class="blogcontainer">
    <div
      v-for="blog in allBlogs"
      :key="blog.id"
      :id="blog.id"
      class="blog flex"
    >
      <img :src="`http://localhost:1337/${blog.img.url}`" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`img` is an array here, you should loop on it or use some index on it aka `blog.img[0].url`.

Comment: hi i try it but i have an error thay url is not define

Comment: Where do you try this? Locally? Is your server running?

Comment: locally
i try it  in my system

Comment: @faezeh Is your local Strapi server running?